# What is the argument used to dsitinguish the cases (a) and (b)

Tags: elliptic-curves

We know from [B. Mazur, Modular curves and the Eisenstein ideal, Publ. math. IHES 47 (1977), 33-186] that if $C$ is an elliptic curve of the form ($C:y²=x³+ax+b$ with $a,b∈ℤ$), then $C(ℚ)^{tors}$ (the subgroup of elements of finite order in $C(ℚ)$ and $C(ℚ)$ is the Mordell-Weil group) is one of the following $15$ groups:

(a) $ℤ/nℤ$, with $1≤n≤10$ or $n=12$, or

(b) $ℤ/2mℤ× ℤ/2ℤ$, $1≤m≤4$.

Note that each of these groups occurs infinitely often as the torsion subgroup of an elliptic curve over $ℚ$. 
My **question** is: .What is the argument (justification) used to dsitinguish the two cases (a) and (b) (given $C/Q$, how do we tell if we are in one case of (a) or one case of (b))?

Comment: Could you clarify your question... what do you mean by "distinguish the two cases"? Do you mean, given $E/\mathbb{Q}$, how do we tell if we are in one case of (a) or one case of (b)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: Yes, this is question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: In you answer you mean ...$E(Q)[2]≅Z/2mZ⊕Z/2Z$ is completely defined over $Q$.

Comment: No, I don't. The two torsion is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, and I mean the case when the $2$ torsion is "full", i.e., isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: So in (b) we have $Z/2mZ×Z/2Z$ is isomorphe to $Z/2mZ⊕Z/2Z$.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @ÁlvaroLozano-Robledo: there is an isomorphism between the tow groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}: y^2=x^3+ax+b$ be an elliptic curve. Then, by Mazur's theorem, $E(\mathbb{Q})_\text{tors}$ falls in case (b) if and only if the two torsion $E(\mathbb{Q})[2]\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is completely defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and this occurs if and only if the polynomial $x^3+ax+b$ factors completely into (non-repeated) linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}$. Notice that in case (a) the two torsion over $\mathbb{Q}$ is either trivial of $E(\mathbb{Q})[2]\cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: To make Alvaro Lozano-Robledo's answer more clear for the less experts, note that the  $2$-torsion points of an elliptic curve in Weierstrass form are the point at infinity (which is actually the zero element of the group) and the three intersections with the $x$-axis, because by simmetry these are the points with tangent meeting the point at infinity of the curve.